# Set the audio of each slide play automatically in the background in PPT via VBA

Tags: vba, audio, powerpoint

I have a PPT file which include a audio (MP3) in each slide. It is not played automatically when I play the PPT (with F5 shortcut), of course, I can set each audio media one by one to play automatically in the background, but is there any VBA method to set them all at once?

Many Many thanks!

Comment: For a answer, which is figured out by myself, please see https://www.jianshu.com/p/c0ea333100c5

Answer (score 2):

[image]

There is an automatic function to have you music play immediately as you open slide-show mode.

You can also customise the delay and control the entrance of the music in the animations pane.

If you want to play the same music across multiple slides, there is an option for that too:
[image]

If you want to use VBA, see [CPearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/PlaySound.aspx).

```
Sub PlayTheSound(ByVal WhatSound As String, Optional Flags As Long = 0)
If Dir(WhatSound, vbNormal) = "" Then
    ' WhatSound is not a file. Get the file named by
    ' WhatSound from the Windows\Media directory.
    WhatSound = Environ("SystemRoot") & "\Media\" & WhatSound
    If InStr(1, WhatSound, ".") = 0 Then
        ' if WhatSound does not have a .wav extension,
        ' add one.
        WhatSound = WhatSound & ".wav"
    End If
    If Dir(WhatSound, vbNormal) = vbNullString Then
        ' Can't find the file. Do a simple Beep.
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    ' WhatSound is a file. Use it.
End If
' Finally, play the sound.
sndPlaySound32 WhatSound, Flags
End Sub
```